# IRC client that allows rich text?

Tags: gratis, linux, android, desktop-client, irc

#### What I'm Looking For

1. An IRC programme (installed or web), plugin, etc. that allows for making rich-text formatting, either directly or through markup (e.g. [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown))?
2. Same thing as #1 but compatible with Android.

#### Requirements

- Gratis.
- No ads.

#### Preferences

- The other person can also see it as such.
- The other person doesn't need to use the same programme/plugin/etc. to do so.
- Free-and-Open-Source (FOSS)

#### Specs

- Computer

  1. *Make & Model*: Dell Inspiron N5010
  2. *Operating System*: Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)
  3. *Environment*: Unity
  4. *Browser Used*: Firefox 42.0 ("Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0")
- Phone

  1. *Make & Model*: Samsung Galaxy Stratosphere II
  2. *Operating System*: Android, v4.1.2 JB
  3. *Browser Used*: Firefox, v42.0.1